# How can I output completely custom content with plugin while still having header, footer, sidebar etc

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

What I want to do is make some url rewrites that will be handled by classes in my plugin. When one of these urls is matched I want to hit an external api and then put out custom html with  the content of api response while still having footer/header/sidebar etc from the current active theme.

I've been testing different methods for a couple of days and seems like outputing my code and the exiting before wordpress runs the default queries could be a good way to do this, but I'm not sure how to use the header/footer from the theme.

Comment: This question is far too broad; you need to show some code and what you have tried for one aspect of your question, i.e. URL rewriting, your API, theme functions, etc.

Comment: Basically I want to make it work much the same way as buddypress does, where they output their custom stuff as a content of a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddypress use custom post type to achieve that. You may not need a custom post type to do that. You can use a page as handler for your plugin and rewrite URLs so that your requested URL is redirected to that page.

Then from your plugin, you can use action hook `template_redirect`. As you are using plugin, you do it like this

```
add_action('template_redirect', array(&$this,'my_custom_template'));
```

Now from `my_custom_template` you can check the page id and serve a different template from your plugin or add filter `the_content` if you only want to change the content of the page.

```
function my_custom_template(){
    if( is_page($my_handler_page_id) ){
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'my_custom_content'));
    }
}
```

Now serve your desired content from `my_custom_content` function

```
function my_custom_content($content){
    $content = "<p>This is custom content</p>";
    .....
    return $content;
}
```

You can also set `query_var` when rewriting URL to take different argument and sent different content checking that `query_var` values.

Comment: Alright thanks, that indeed looks like a better way to achieve this, then what buddypress does.

Comment: One more question, is template_redirect the right hook if I need to do quite a lot of stuff before outputing the content, like hitting external api, then database and only after that outputing the content?

Comment: @Kramer In `template_redirect` you should only load a template or other filter like `the_content` to generate the page. At least that way, user can see header and some other content while they wait for main page content.